# which variable is selected at each node

Tags: visual-c++, cplex

I wrote a code and used concert technology(cplex  and C++). Now I want to get some information about variable selection. For example I want to know that at each node which variable is selected among 10 variables.
how can i write this and add it to my code?

Comment: What have you done so far? Have a look at cplex MIP Callback.

Answer (score 1):

As @IagoCarvalho suggested, you should have a look at the Branch callback:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/progr_adv/callbacks_basic/15_catalog.html.

Examples using a branch callback can be found in an installation of the product. Look for "branch callback" in the `cplex/examples/src` directory and you will find, among others, `cpp/iloadmipex3.cpp`.

Comment: could you please give me more information about how  to implement a branchcallback? Becasue i didn't understand CPLEX manual reference .

Comment: As Xavier suggested, the examples show you exactly how to do this. So, please take a look at `iloadmipex1.cpp` and `iloadmipex3.cpp`. These examples are included when you install CPLEX.